# Find electrostatic energy - Is there a typo?

Tags: energy, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, textbook-erratum

The problem asks me "Show that the electrostatic energy $U$ of a charge $q$, subject to an electric potential $\Phi(\boldsymbol r)$ is $U = q \Phi(\boldsymbol r)$

**My trial**

The electrostatic energy is just the work, so recall the definition of work is $$U = \int_{\boldsymbol a}^{\boldsymbol b}\boldsymbol F \cdot d\boldsymbol s$$ in our case, since there is an electric potential, there must be an electric field generating it. We should have $\boldsymbol E = -\nabla \Phi$. Hence we have $\boldsymbol F = q\boldsymbol E$. Also recall that we have $$\Delta\Phi(\boldsymbol r)=-\int_{\boldsymbol r_0}^{\boldsymbol r}\boldsymbol E \cdot d \boldsymbol s=\Phi(\boldsymbol r)-\Phi(\boldsymbol r_0)$$ so then $$U = \int_{\boldsymbol r_0}^{r}q\boldsymbol E \, \cdot \, d\boldsymbol s = q\int_{\boldsymbol r_0}^{r}\boldsymbol E \, \cdot \, d\boldsymbol s = -q (\Phi(\boldsymbol r)- \Phi(\boldsymbol r_0))$$ Now, here it is not stated, but I guess we can choose the reference point to be asymptotical infinity and so we would get $U = - q\Phi(\boldsymbol r)$

Why do I get a minus sign? What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is an often asked question.  You need to work out the work done by an external force which is minus the work done by the field.  $\boldsymbol F_{\rm external} = q\boldsymbol E$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The electrostatic energy is actually minus the work done by the electric force, so that more the work done by the electric force the more you lose the potential energy (and gain kinetic energy in its place).

So, start with

$$U = -\int_{\boldsymbol a}^{\boldsymbol b}\boldsymbol F_e \cdot d\boldsymbol s$$ where $\boldsymbol F_e $ is the force due to electic field.

Answer (score 1):

Abhijeet's and Farcher's answers are correct. Another way to look at it is as follows.

The mathematical statement is that for a path-independent vector field $\vec{v}(r)$, the following identity holds:

$$\vec{v}=\nabla_r \int_{r_0}^r \vec{v}\cdot d\vec{s}$$

Note that the signs are correct, because in one dimension this is just the fundamental theorem of calculus: $f(r)=\frac{d}{dr} \int_{r_0}^r f(s) ds$. Then we have $\vec{E}=\nabla_r \int_{r_0}^r \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}$ as a mathematical identity, and we demand also $\vec{E}=-\nabla_r \Phi$. Put these two equations together to find: $$\Phi(r)=-\int_{r_0}^r \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}$$